# How to print arabic words from c# windows forms ? using line printer code

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void print()
{
  LPrinter MyPrinter;

  MyPrinter = new LPrinter(printerName);

            MyPrinter.Open("");

            string date = dtPrintermain.Rows[0]["date"].ToString();
            string Billno = dtPrintermain.Rows[0]["inv_no"].ToString();
            MyPrinter.Print( "جمعيةصباحالناصرالتعاونية" +" \r\n");
            MyPrinter.Print(" ".PadRight(40, '_') + "\r\n");
            MyPrinter.Print((date).PadLeft(5, ' ') + "تاريخ".PadRight(10, ' ') + Billno.PadRight(10, ' ') + "رقم الفاتورة".PadRight(10, ' ') + "\r\n");
            MyPrinter.Print(" ".PadRight(40, '_') + "\r\n");
``                DataTable dtOrderDetails = new ConnectionClass().ExecuteDataTable(billdetails);
            MyPrinter.Print("________________________________________\r\n");
            MyPrinter.Print("السعر".PadRight(12, ' ') + "الكمية".PadRight(18, ' ') + "الصنف".PadRight(10, ' ') + "\r\n");
            MyPrinter.Print("________________________________________\r\n");


            MyPrinter.Print("________________________________________\r\n");
            string GrandTotal = cls.todouble(dtPrintermain.Rows[0]["total"].ToString()).ToString();
            MyPrinter.Print("".PadRight(20, ' ') + "GrandTotal:".PadLeft(10, ' ') + (GrandTotal).PadLeft(10, ' ') + "\r\n");
            MyPrinter.Print("\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
            MyPrinter.Print(LPrinter.eCut);
            MyPrinter.Close();

        }


// LP Printer Class is below




public LPrinter(String printerName)
    {
        HandlePrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
        ps = new PrinterSettings();
        ps.PrinterName = printerName;
    }

    public string PrinterName
    {
        get
        {
            return ps.PrinterName;
        }
        set
        {
            ps.PrinterName = value;
        }
    }
    public bool ChoosePrinter()
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = ps;
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ps = pd.PrinterSettings;
            return true;
        }`enter code here`
        else return false;
    }

    public bool Open(string DocName)
    {
        // see if printer is already open
        if (HandlePrinter != IntPtr.Zero) return false;

        // opens the printer
        bool risp = OpenPrinter(ps.PrinterName, out HandlePrinter, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (risp == false) return false;

        // starts a print job
        DOCINFOA MyDocInfo = new DOCINFOA();
        MyDocInfo.pDocName = DocName;
        MyDocInfo.pOutputFile = null;
        MyDocInfo.pDataType = "RAW";

        if (StartDocPrinter(HandlePrinter, 1, MyDocInfo))
        {
            StartPagePrinter(HandlePrinter); //starts a page       
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public bool Close()
    {
        if (HandlePrinter == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
        if (!EndPagePrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        if (!EndDocPrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        if (!ClosePrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        HandlePrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
        return true;
    }


    public bool Print(string outputstring)
    {
        if (HandlePrinter == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("a");
            return false;
        }
        IntPtr buf = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(outputstring);
        Int32 done = 0;
        bool ok = WritePrinter(HandlePrinter, buf, outputstring.Length, out done);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buf);

        if (!ok) return false;
        else return true;
    }
```

Out put is

> ????????

Not displaying anything in arabic

Comment: WHat's the implementation of `Print`?

Comment: for print point of sales in thermal printer EPSON

Comment: Hi, unless you post the implementation of `MyPrinter.Print` we cannot answer your question properly. Usually these kind of 'problems' are based on code-pages and printer capabilities. For now I am voting to close this question as it cannot be answered.

Comment: you know  what is reason  to print  Question mark  "???"  when i print arabic

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you are running an English version of Windows, rather than an Arabic version. That is, your system's default code page is not one that includes Arabic characters.

In .NET, all strings are Unicode, so that doesn't matter. That is by design—Windows has had full Unicode support for two decades now, and all applications should be using it.

Your problem is this line, in the `Print` function:

```
IntPtr buf = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(outputstring);
```

The `Ansi` suffix at the end of that function means that it is going to convert the `outputstring` into an ANSI string. In Windows parlance, an "ANSI" string is one that uses the system's default code page. In other words, a non-Unicode string. ANSI code pages are very limited, and only support a subset of characters. The supported characters are different on different code pages.

If your system's default code page doesn't have Arabic characters, as I suspect, then the conversion to an ANSI string is going to fail. Characters that cannot be represented in the ANSI code page will be converted into question marks.

Always use the Unicode variants of functions that deal with strings. There is never a reason to use ANSI strings. In this case, that would mean that you should be calling the `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni` function, which is the Unicode version.

Except that won't work either, but for a different reason. The [`WritePrinter` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145226.aspx) is not a COM function. It doesn't want a COM string, so you should not be marshalling the string as one.

Rather, this is an old Win32 function that accepts a pointer to an array of bytes (in other words, a C-style string). You could try passing it a Unicode string, but that may not work. Really, all that this function does is send a raw stream of bytes directly to your printer hardware. It requires that you have detailed knowledge about the way your printer hardware works. There might be a way to switch the printer into Unicode mode so that it interprets the sequence of bytes as UTF-16 characters. I don't know—check your printer manual.

If you just send arbitrary data to the printer, you'll get arbitrary data out. In 99% of cases, you should not be printing using a raw binary interface. Use a higher-level API, one that allows you to send actual text to the printer. There are several to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

The `LPrinter` class seems to be this [code sample on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29709/Line-Printer-Class-in-C) from 2008 (judging from the method names, did not verify), and the discussion there raised the question about Arabic, which was promptly [answered](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4551809/Re-Arabic-Fonts-doesnt-work-correctly.aspx)

> to my knowledge, Line Printers do not support Arabic Fonts unless you
>   switch to graphic mode (opposed to text mode).
>
> The class presented in the article was made for text mode only, but of
>   course you can always send commands to print in graphic mode (but in
>   this case you have to handle that by yourself--check the other
>   answers, we have discussed about that).